# Lattice vibrations via Lagrangian mechanics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, solid-state-physics

When solving the Lagrangian for the one dimensional atomic chain. I get stuck at proving an identity.

So my Lagrangian is

$  L=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\frac{m}{2} \dot{\phi}_{n}^{2}-\frac{k_{s}}{2}\left(\phi_{n+1}-\phi_{n}\right)^{2}\right]  $

$  \partial_{\phi_{n}} L=-k_{s}\left(\phi_{n}-\phi_{n+1}\right)-k_{s}\left(\phi_{n}-\phi_{n-1}\right)  $

$  \left(\phi_{n+1}-2 \phi_{n}+\phi_{n-1}\right)  $

I'm trying to turn this expression into $  a^2 \partial_{x}^2 \phi(x)  $

So I was thinking. By definition.

$  \phi_{n+1}-\phi_{n} \rightarrow a \partial_{x} \phi(x)  $

But this would give us the answer before I differentiate once with respect to $ \phi(x) $

I can't seem to think of a manipulation that would give me the desired result, any thoughts ? This was given to me by my professor to prove. But I don't think I can but would still like to know the answer. Thank you in advance